# RCTFont.h file not found

Tags: xcode, reactjs, react-native

Trying to run the simulator on xCode version 10.1 and this error is appearing. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90wvt.png)

The error also appears here [Code segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6HCK.png)

I am unsure as to find and link this file, or even create it. Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i got the same problem. any fix ?